# Shiny Dashboard Sidebar not the same width as Header logo CSS

Tags: html, css, r, shinydashboard

Creating a custom theme for my dashboard but I am running into a slight hiccup. I am adding borders to the sidebar and header but when I do, they seem to not align. Looking at the Inspect elements, the widths are off slightly 228.2 versus 229.01.

Any idea of how to align this border on the sidebar so it looks continuous between header logo area and sidebar? I would rather find the root of the problem versus just using css to change the width{} of one.

Below is the code and css that shows this problem:

```
library (shiny)
library (shinydashboard)
library (shinydashboardPlus)
library (shinyjs)

rm(list=ls())

###########################/ui.R/##################################

#Header----
header <- dashboardHeaderPlus(
  title = "MRO Dash"
  ,
  enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,
  rightSidebarIcon = "sliders"
)

#Right SideBar----
rightsidebar <- rightSidebar()

#SideBar----
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  #Sidebar Menu----
  div(id = "sidebarChoices",
      #style = "position: fxed; overflow: visible;", 
      sidebarMenu(id = "menuChoice",
                  menuItem("Functional Dashboards", tabName = "MetricMenu", icon = icon("dashboard"),
                           menuSubItem("Operations", tabName = "OpsMetricSubMenu", icon = icon("angle-double-right"))
                  ),
                  menuItem("Test Dashboards", tabName = "2", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                  menuItem("Salt Dashboards", tabName = "3", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                  menuItem("Pepper Dashboards", tabName = "4", icon = icon("dashboard"))          
      )
  )



  #End )----
) #dashboard sidebar end

#Body----
body <- dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  #CSS Formatting----
  #Background colors----
  #tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".sidebar {height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;}"))),
  tags$head(tags$link(rel="shortcut icon", href="favicon.ico")), 

  #   /* other links in the sidebarmenu when hovered */
  # .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a:hover{background-color: #E4551F;}
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                            /*** FORMATTING BACKGROUND COLORS ***/

                            /* Header */

                            .skin-blue .main-header {
                            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
                            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                            }

                            .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                            background-color: #3A3F44;
                            border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
                            color: #f8f9fa;
                            }
                            .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                            background-color: #3A3F44;
                            border-left: 1px solid rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.3);
                            }

                            .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle{
                            color: #f8f9fa;
                            }

                            .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .nav>li>a {
                            color: #f8f9fa;
                            }

                            /* Main SideBar */
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar {
                            background-color: #272B30;
                            color: #f8f9fa;
                            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
                            box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(170, 170, 170, 0.3);


                            }
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu a{
                            background-color: #272B30;
                            color: #f8f9fa;

                            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
                            text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                            }


                            /* Hover Color */
                            .skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {background-color: #E4551F;}
                            .skin-blue .main-sidebar .sidebar .sidebar-menu .active a{background-color: #E4551F;}
                            .skin-blue .sidebar-menu > li.active > a {border-left-color: #E4551F;}
                            .skin-blue .sidebar-menu > li.active > a, .skin-blue .sidebar-menu > li:hover > a {border-left-color: #E4551F;}
                            .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .nav > li:hover > a {background-color: #E4551F;}   
                            .skin-blue .main-header .navbar .sidebar-toggle:hover{background-color: #E4551F;}                            




                            /* Right SideBar */
                            .control-sidebar-dark+.control-sidebar-bg {background: #272B30;}
                            .control-sidebar-dark+.nav.nav-tabs.nav-justified.control-sidebar-tabs {background: #272B30;}
                            .control-sidebar-dark+.control-sidebar.control-sidebar-dark.control-sidebar-open {background: #272B30;}

                            /* Body */ 
                            .content-wrapper, .right-side {background-color: #272B30;}

                            ')))
  )
#Builds Dashboard Page----
ui <- dashboardPagePlus(header, sidebar, body, rightsidebar)

###########################/server.R/###############################
server <- function(input, output, session) {


}

#Combines Dasboard and Data together----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```